# Render reactjs component not work localhost

Tags: reactjs

Please,can somebody help to solve my problem with react.I am trying to render Hello World in div named header,but is shows nothing. I use localhost with server.js

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
 <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Link on image: 
http://prntscr.com/j2r5wr

errors:

http://prntscr.com/j2rd5s

Comment: Please add the parts of the code that are relevant for your question *as text directly into the question* instead of linking to a screenshot of code.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake in dom render at first:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Helloworld />, 
  document.getElementById('header')
);
```

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
react-dom.development.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
browser.js:9187 Uncaught SyntaxError: http://localhost:3000/main.js: Unterminated JSX contents (8:14)
    at Parser.pp.raise (browser.js:2028)
    at Parser.pp.jsx_readToken (browser.js:25748)
    at Parser.jsx_readToken (browser.js:735)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (browser.js:26085)
    at Parser.readToken (browser.js:728)
    ........

Comment: Seems like jsx env set up missing, please read the docs how to set up environment.

Answer (score 0):

3 ways of creating component. Dont need to use React.createClass(as in picture)

1. simple functional component that directly returns some jsx

   const HelloWord = () => (

   ## Hello word!!

   )
2. normal funtional component

   const HelloWord = () => {
     return (

   ## Hello word!!

   )
   }
3. Class component

   class HelloWord extends React.Component {
     render() {
       return (

   ## Hello word!!

   )
     }
   }

and then use it like

```
render(<HelloWord />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```